# Ошибка: Incorrect configuration VectorDrawableCompat при запуске приложения

Tags: java, android

В общем создаю я android проект, использую IntelliJ IDEA. Выбираю я *Blank Activity*, все создается, все нормально.

Но когда я пытаюсь запустить это приложение на AVD, то в эмуляторе появляется ошибка типа "`Unfortunately, %nameApp% has stoped`" в логе *FATAL EXCEPTION* (смотри ниже)

[image: Скриншот консоли]

**Первая и вторая строки**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.maxde.rgbcircle/com.example.maxde.rgbcircle.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This app has been built with an incorrect configuration. Please configure your build for VectorDrawableCompat.
```

Comment: Возможно, что-то не так с конкретной версией  `IntelliJ IDEA`. Мне казется, что она подключает неправильную версию support библиотеки. Используйте лучше Android Studio последней стабильной версии

Comment: Так и сделал. Перешел на Android Studio. Тут все как надо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

По всей видимости в файл конфигурации модуля приложения *build.gradle* нужно добавить поддержку `VectorDrawable`

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
  }
}
```

Так же версия плагина Gradle должна быть не менее 2.x.x (*build.gradle* всего проекта):

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
    ...
}
```

Comment: Появляются другие ошибки.

Comment: @CGLike Сочувствую вам. Попробуйте с таким описанием ошибок обратиться к экстрасенсам, что ли ...

Comment: Хорошо я попробую, ценный совет.
И я спрашивал только об одной ошибке, решил проблему переходом на Android Studio.