# Не могу добавить новый Vector в проект

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Хочу добавить новый вектор в проект, выбираю иконку из Material icon, иконка не появляется в preview, а кнопка Next не нажимается. Перед этим все работало. В чем может быть проблема? Кто что посоветует?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В конфиг gradle [поддержку добавили](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/541540/177345) ?

Comment: Не обязательно же в конфигурацию писать поддержку вектора. Он тогда в png конвертирует